# EXCEL - Combine rows based on ID with no loss of data which is spread across columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have received an export from a database which contains a huge amount of duplicated records.

There are approx 8000 records with over 100 columns. Issues with data relating to the unique ID being spread across about 5 columns are causing duplications. I expect about 1500 actual unique records.

I have attached a simplified version of what I have and what i'm trying to achieve.

I feel like there could be a solution along the lines of of: merge the rows, if data = the same OK otherwise take non-nulls. Is there something that could be down in power query?

Thanks!
Helen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw0Ut.png)

Answer (score 2):

Apply a simple **GROUP** (right click on id column and select **Group**) in **Power Query** as shown below.

[image]

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Hi R_R thanks so much for the feedback. That works perfectly for the example I gave however when I try this with the real data it doesn't include the other columns (about 100 columns in total) - do you know if there is any additional workaround for this situation? Thanks, Helen

Comment: You have to add all columns in the aggregation part. Here only sample 3, add other 97 in the list :)